# Adding run-time dependencies for Allegro addons?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dependency-management, allegro, allegro5

I'm trying to use some of the Allegro addon libraries.

For instance:

```
#include <allegro5/allegro_primitives.h>
```

But MSVS10 is telling me the things I'm referencing are undefined. I got the standard

```
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
```

to work just fine, and now I'm guessing I need to be adding more runtime dependencies for the addons as well. But I have no idea how to do that, nor could I find a guide/list to say what values need to be added to which value fields in the properties.

Comment: The strange thing, to my eyes, is that the include is legit. The compiler sees no error, it recognizes it just fine. And those two includes obviously follow the same path, and one's function references work and the other's don't. That makes no sense to me.

Comment: The plot thickens! I can access SOME of the functions in the primitives library, such as al_draw_triangle or al_init_primitives_addon() but not all of them, such as the one I want-- al_draw_filled_polygon. WTF?

Comment: Omg, I think it's the version. For some reason the version I just downloaded from the Allegro site is not the newest version, and therefore does not contain these functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://alleg.sourceforge.net/a5docs/refman/primitives.html#al_draw_filled_polygon:

> Since: 5.1.0

The pre-built binaries are from the 5.0 "stable" series. The 5.1 series is "development" which means things can change from version to version. Some features may make it into the 5.0 series, while most will not be around until the next stable series (5.2).

So short version is, if you want those features now, you'll need to build 5.1 yourself.

Comment: Are you the only other person on SO who follows the Allegro tag?